# PHP File Upload Isn't Working

Tags: php, html, file-upload

So I built this simple script to upload files to an XAMPP server, and  . . . it didn't work. When I ran it, it dies after the first `if` statement. EDIT: FIXED

Here's the FIXED html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Awesome Life: File Upload</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="forms.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="big_wrap">
    <section id="sign_up">
        <form action="http://localhost/mail.php" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
            <span id="upText">File to Upload</span> 
            <br />
            <input style="margin-top:5px;" type="file" name="fileName">
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" id="button" name="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the FIXED script:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_FILES["fileName"])){
    die("It didn't work!");
}else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"], "\xampp\htdocs\".$_FILES["fileName"]  ["name"]) or die("Didn't work");
}
?>
```

The file type isn't determined or tested, as I'm not going to be using this on the World Wide Web. I'm simply wondering why it doesn't work. Thanks!

EDIT: It was a simple matter of changing the edit permissions of the htdocs folder. I unchecked the read-only box and it worked fine. Thanks to all for contributing, and especially to Fred -ii-

Comment: We're gonna need to know more than just "It doesn't work tell me why". What is in your php.ini files regarding file uploads? How big is the file you're uploading and what MIME type does it have? (There is a default MB upload value that you may have to adjust)

Comment: These are the rules specified in the php.ini:                            file_uploads=On,
upload_tmp_dir=C:\xampp\tmp,
upload_max_filesize=2M,
max_file_uploads=20,

Comment: [`Read the manual`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) and make sure folders have write permissions. @crazyjedi98 and you probably need another \ in `"\xampp\htdocs"` as `"\xampp\htdocs\"` or may need to do  `"/xampp/htdocs/"`

Comment: Fred -ii-, you are beast. All I had to do was remove the "read-only" permission from the htdocs folder and add another slash to the end. The other answers helped a lot, too.

Comment: Aahhhh good, nice to hear it's solved!! :)

Comment: Actually, my answer is the one that should be accepted, but I don't do it for the points. What I mean by this is, when people who visit the question, will see what the actual problem was, and not the `multipart/file-data` that you had and edited (and did not work), but the write permission and missing slash which I had mentioned. @crazyjedi98 It's just barring the T's and dotting the I's. There's nothing wrong with changing your mind. ;-)

Comment: Actually, it was a combination of both yours and Niet's answer that helped solve the problem. The missing 'form-data' would've caused just as much an issue as the write permission. As for everyone not noticing you . . . HEY FOLKS IT WAS FRED -ii- THAT SOLVED A BIG HALF OF MA PROBLEM! CHECK OUT HIS COMMENTS ON THE QUESTION!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multipart/file-data` is incorrect. It should be `multipart/form-data` instead.

Also, you should use [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move-uploaded-file) to move the uploaded file somewhere. Not `copy`.

Comment: Changed the file-data to form-data and there's no difference. Also used the move_uploaded_file() and it didn't work, either. All I'm uploading for practice is a small .jpg file, 3.67 KB.

Comment: HEY FOLKS IT WAS FRED -ii- THAT SOLVED A BIG HALF OF MA PROBLEM AS WELL! CHECK OUT HIS COMMENTS ON THE QUESTION!!!!

Answer (score 2):

replace `form` attribute

```
ENCTYPE="multipart/file-data"
```

to

```
ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a mix of many things, but as OP stated: (***and more importantly***)

*"Fred -ii-, you are beast. All I had to do was remove the "read-only" permission from the htdocs folder and add another slash to the end. The other answers helped a lot, too"*

Answer transformed from [`my comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074140/php-file-upload-isnt-working#comment33475711_22074140):

(Main problem)
Make sure folders have write permissions. and you probably need another `\` in `"\xampp\htdocs"` as `"\xampp\htdocs\"` or may need to do `"/xampp/htdocs/"`